# Get the string and append it before a variable name

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple multilingual web site. (Data will be stored in a DB laterly) Basically I will have columns starting with language string on my table like tr_text and en_text... I am not sure if that's a proper way to do it.

My DB will look like that:

```
--------------------------------
# | en_text      | tr_text      
--------------------------------
1 | English Text | Turkish Text
--------------------------------
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    $get_lang = $_GET['language'];

    if ($get_lang == 'tr') {
        $lang = 'tr_';
    } else if ($get_lang == 'en') {
        $lang    = 'en_';
    }

    $tr_text = 'Turkish Text'; // It will be stored in my DB 
    $en_text = 'English Text'; // It will be also stored in my DB 
?>

<body>

    <?php echo $lang.'text'; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You’d need [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to achieve that, and those should rather be avoided. And as for “properly” implementing such translations, that is an already broadly discussed topic, and several sophisticated solutions exist – you might want to use the keywords [`i18n` and/or `L10n`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) in your further research.

Comment: $field = $lang.'text';
Select $field from table;

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not a good idea , you should turn to array

**lang_en.php :**

```
<?php
    $lang = array('hi' => 'Hi',
                  'user' => 'User');

?>
```

**lang_tr.php :**

```
<?php
    $lang = array('hi'   => 'Hola',
                  'user' => 'bla bla bla');
?>
```

**anypage.php**

```
<?php

 $lang= "tr";// or en
 include("lang_".$lang.".php");

echo $lang['hi']; //output Hi for en , and Hola for tr
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the easiest way to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should store translations in a separate table.

That table will store class name, object id, field name, a language string and a transalation.

You can take a look how doctrine translatable works, and use it, or implement something simple by yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using PHP's gettext();

http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2002/06/13/php.html